# Run entire script for multiple IDs of a single dataframe

Tags: r, list, loops

I have a data frame with several thousand locations, each belonging to a different ID with >100 IDs. I am trying to run an entire script with a final output including a shapefile for each individual ID.

The data looks like this:

```
ID Easting  Northing
1  593853   5255971
1  593660   5253841 
1  594513   5253841
2  583242   5258672
2  583436   5258031
3  593983   5258470
3  591849   5258471
3  591784   5258974
3  591984   5258093
4  591948   5259012
4  591947   5259016
5  578452   5261983
```

The dataframe has 60+ locations per ID. I've written about a 100 line script to subset the data for 1 single ID and carrying through an analysis to get a shapefile at the end, but I'm wondering if there is there a way to automatically do this for all the IDs. This is how the scripts starts:

```
maju<-read.csv("JuvenileRelocations.csv",header=T)
str(maju)
maju$ID <- as.factor(maju$ID)

ma161 <- subset(maju, maju$ID == "1") #subset for 1 id
ma161<-ma161[!is.na(ma161$easting) & !is.na(ma161$northing),]#remove missing locations
##Get only the coordinates
loc <- data.frame("x"=ma161$easting, "y"=ma161$northing)


##Define the projection of the coordinates
proj4string <- CRS("+proj=utm +zone=15 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")

##Make SpatialPointsDataFrame using the XY, attributes, and projection
spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(loc, maju, proj4string = proj4string)

##run the rest of the code using spdf for ID 1 
#####
#####
#####
#final line will be for output shapefile for ID1
writeOGR(hpikde.80vol,dsn="output", layer="ma161plug95",driver="ESRI Shapefile",overwrite=TRUE)
```

Everything works for just one individual, can I make it automatically go back to the beginning of the script and do the same thing for ID 2, ID 3 etc etc.
I am learning R on my own so I'm sure there is a way to do this, I'm just not familiar enough yet.
Thanks in advance for any help!

SOLVE...Ok I solved this using a for loop as per user1505631 's suggestion. The code as follows for anyone who wants to see it.

```
maju<-read.csv("JuvenileRelocations.csv",header=T)
str(maju)
maju$ID <- as.factor(maju$ID)
maju<-maju[!is.na(maju$easting) & !is.na(maju$northing),]
#this to practice on just the first 5 individuals to save computing time
innames<-unique(maju$ID) 
innames<-innames[1:5]
outnames<-innames
##Define the projection of the coordinates
proj4string <- CRS("+proj=utm +zone=15 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 
+units=m +no_defs")

for (i in 1:length(innames)){
  data <- maju[which(maju$ID==innames[i]),]
   if(dim(data)[1] != 0){
    #get the coordinates
    data.xy<-data[c("easting", "northing")]
     ##Make SpatialPointsDataFrame using the XY, attributes, and projection
    spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(data.xy, data, proj4string = 
proj4string)
##run the rest of the analysis and export shapefile at end
#####
#####
#####
#write shapefile for each id
writeOGR(hpikde.95vol,dsn = "output", layer=paste(outnames[i], 
"KUD95", sep=""), driver="ESRI Shapefile",overwrite=TRUE)
   }
}
```

Comment: Why would a loop not work: something like
for(i in unique(maju$ID)){
  maI <- subset(maju, maju$ID == i) #subset for id

...
}

Comment: Ok thanks @user1505631 . Read up on for loops and solved using your suggestion, added the code to my original Q. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sp)

proj4string <- CRS("+proj=utm +zone=15 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")

read_table("~/Downloads/JuvenileRelocations.csv") %>%
  filter(!is.na(Easting), !is.na(Northing)) %>%
  summarise(spdf = list(SpatialPointsDataFrame(data.frame(x = Easting, y = Northing), data.frame(ID), proj4string = proj4string)), .by = ID)
```